# What is the format of pytorch models?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, binary

I have to create a workflow that uses pytorch models or torch script models in c++. However, I can't find the binary format. I tried looking through the serializer but to no avail. Does anybody have documentation or code that gives me a clue as to the model format?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Answer (score 1):

[PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) has a great [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) of ***Tracing***/***Scripting*** models and ***Loading*** them via **C++**.